# htaccess setup for rest api to handle directories that do not exist

Tags: php, rest, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a terrible time and not sure if I'm overthinking it. I'm trying to create a rest API in php (may not matter).  I want to have the uri in the format /api/research/data/2020. I created the directory "research" but nothing below that. In the htaccess file, I have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/api/research/data/$ /api/research/index.php [NC,L]
```

I keep getting results that /api/research/ does not exist (it's true, it doesn't). I have tried to be literal and I have tried various pattern matching. I have googled around and tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be getting me what I need.

Main question: does `/api/research/` need to exist? Does `/api/research/data/` ? Or if not, what might I be doing wrong?

Thank you!

UPDATE May 26, 2020: I finally got this working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mobile/list/?$ RestController.php?view=all [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^mobile/list/([0-9])+/? RestController.php?view=single&id=$1 [nc,qsa]
```

1) The main issue I was having was starting off with ^/ instead of just ^. As soon as I made that change, it cleared right up. I do NOT need to create any of these directories.

2) The .htaccess file needs to be at the public_html level. I had it in a subdirectory trying to match the target.

Comment: Before that _RewriteRule_ add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` so it will redirect only when directory doesn't exist.

Comment: And yes, `/api/research` should exist and having `index.php` inside to manage requests.

Comment: Thank you. So if I want to use /api/research/data/, I also need an existing "data" directory with index.php? What about examples I've seen with a dynamic value at the end, for example /products/66432, how would I handle that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to rewrite using wildcards and then filter the endpoints of the API in PHP:

```
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php [nc,qsa]
```